# Postgres: cast, money and NULL values

Tags: postgresql

In my select I am using this in order to convert an integer to a money form.

```
CAST(mytable.discount AS money) AS Discount
```

But I cannot figure out how to avoid the 'NULL' output if the join fails (for good cause) to bring the optional value.

I've done this to avoid NULLS in the past:

```
COALESCE(mytable.voucher,'----') AS Voucher
```

But I cannot figure out how to combined CAST and COALESCE for the same field. I just want my discount NULL fields to be '----'

Comment: `COALESCE(CAST(mytable.discount AS money), '-----')`

Comment: That's tricky, as the "mytable.discount AS money" converts NULLS to $0, which is what it outputs. '-----' never comes to play.

Comment: "*I just want my discount NULL fields to be '----'*" - you can't. `'---'` is a character value, `discount` is a number. You can't have different datatypes for the same column. You would need to convert all numbers to a string as value (e.g. using `to_char()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That's tricky, as the "mytable.discount AS money" converts NULLS to $0

It's actually not what happens, but an implicit cast which happens *after that*.

An expression must have a particular type. In this case it's `money`. So you see `$0.00` as a result of my proposed expression because it's `----` that is converted to `money`, not `NULL`.

As a solution you may explicitly convert the inner expression to text like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST('1' as money)::text, '--');
```

or

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(null as money)::text, '--');
```

SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/2866